# Git merge is automatically accepting incoming changes even though there is a conflict

Tags: git

I am new to git and recently I have encountered a problem that is

**once I merge my feature_branch with main and continue to work on the feature_branch and merge it again with main...The main automatically accepts the incoming changes. Whereas during the first merge...I got an option to either accept the incoming change or not.**

this is how I did the process in VS code terminal

```
git clone "..."
create a file
written some code and committed it in main
git branch feature_branch
git checkout feature_branch
modified the same code so as to get a conflict
git commit -am "..."
git checkout main
git merge feature_branch
```

as this is the first merge...I got an option in VS code to either keep the current changes or accept the incoming changes or compare them.
later I added some code into main as well as feature_branch...to bring the conflict again but this time when I merge into main..even though there is a conflict, somehow it is automatically accepting incoming changes.

this is how I get a message after I type **git merge feature_branch** for the second time.

```
Fast-forward
 README.md | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

My intention is to get the conflict resolution options every time I do git merge...

Comment: I could explain why the second merge would not produce a conflict, but I do not understand why your first merge produced a conflict---it shouldn't if one follows your sequence of commands strictly. Are you sure you branched `feature_branch` off of the commit that you describe as `and committed it in main`, or did you actually branch off from an earlier commit?

Comment: I am sorry, could you please explain in a simpler way I didnt understand what you were asking

Comment: yes, you were right..I did the exact same steps by creating a new repo and it did not ask for manual conflict resolution..just overwitten what is there in feature_branch

Comment: What makes you think there is a conflict?